# r shiny - apply function to columns chosen via pickerInput

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, reactive

I am attempting to pass a selected set of columns of a reactive data table to a user-defined function.  I would like to be able to choose the columns via `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets`.   I am not getting an error but the drop down that usually comes from `pickerInput` isn't appearing.  I figured putting `pickerInput` in a `renderUI` would work but for some reason it isn't.

I have tried doing this with a minimal reproducible example using the `RLdata10000` dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(RecordLinkage)
data("RLdata10000")
library(shinyWidgets)


removeSPE <- function(x) gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)

cleanup <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(x) # convert to character
  x <- tolower(x) # make all lowercase
  x <- sapply(x, removeSPE) # remove special characters
  x <- trimws(x, "both") # since stopwords have been removed, there is extra white space left, this removes it
  x <- gsub("(?<=\\b\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "", x, perl = TRUE) # removes whitespace btwn two single chars
  return(x)
}
```

***UI***

```
##### APP BEGINS HERE WITH UI #####

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Record Linkage",
         tabPanel("Load"
                  , dataTableOutput("records")
         ),
         tabPanel("Weights Method"
                  ,plotOutput("weightplot")
                  ,sliderInput("lowerthreshold", "Weight Lower threshold:",
                               min = 0.0, max = 1.0,
                               value =0.2)
                  ,sliderInput("upperthreshold", "Weight Upper threshold:",
                               min = 0.0, max = 1.0,
                               value =0.5)

                  ,dataTableOutput("weights")
         )
  )
)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
```

***SERVER***

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(file1 = RLdata10000)
  output$records <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
  inputId = "pick_col",
  label = "select columns to clean:",
  choices = colnames(data$file1),
  selected = colnames(data$file1),
  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                 `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file1)) - 1),
                 `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                 liveSearch = TRUE,
                 liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
  multiple = TRUE)

  })

  output$records <- renderDataTable({
RLdata10000 <-  cbind((lapply(RLdata10000[, 1:4], cleanup)), RLdata10000[5:7])
  })


  output$weights <- renderDataTable({
rec.pairs <- compare.dedup(RLdata10000
                           ,blockfld = list(1, 5:7)
                           ,strcmp =   c(2,3,4)
                           ,strcmpfun = levenshteinSim)
pairs.weights <- emWeights(rec.pairs)

pairs.classify <- emClassify(pairs.weights, threshold.upper = input$upperthreshold, threshold.lower = input$lowerthreshold)
final.results <- pairs.classify$pairs
final.results$weight <- pairs.classify$Wdata
final.results$links <- pairs.classify$prediction

    final.results

      })

  output$weightplot <- renderPlot({
rec.pairs <- compare.dedup(RLdata10000
                           ,blockfld = list(1, 5:7)
                           ,strcmp =   c(2,3,4)
                           ,strcmpfun = levenshteinSim)
pairs.weights <- epiWeights(rec.pairs)

    hist(pairs.weights$Wdata)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Choose a set of columns via `pickerInput` drop down
2. Apply the function `cleanup` defined above to the set of columns chosen
3. Display the output in a reactive datatable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't specify a `uiOutput` anywhere in your `ui`, and you've also named two outputs "records". You need to put `uiOutput("records")` somewhere in your `ui` and change the name of either that or the table so that you don't have duplicated outputs.

Comment: Thanks.  I specify a `dataTableOutput` why is it that I need both?

Comment: The `dataTableOutput` takes care of the data table, but the `pickerInput` is a UI element that you need to specify separately, just as you do in your second `tabPanel`. See below for a partial response (i.e., it only addresses part 1 of your request, not parts 2 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `uiOutput` so that the app knows where in the UI to put the elements you're asking for. You also had the same names for two output elements (the `renderUI` and the `dataTableOutput`), which will cause problems. Replace the relevant parts of your ui and server definitions with the following to get the `pickerInput` to show. Note that this doesn't address applying the function to columns you select, so this is only a partial answer.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Record Linkage",
             tabPanel("Load"
                      , uiOutput("colselect")
                      , dataTableOutput("records")
             ),
             tabPanel(
             # ... code omitted here
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(file1 = RLdata10000)
  output$colselect <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "pick_col",
      label = "select columns to clean:",
      choices = colnames(data$file1),
      selected = colnames(data$file1),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                     `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file1)) - 1),
                     `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                     liveSearch = TRUE,
                     liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
      multiple = TRUE)

  })

  output$records <- renderDataTable({
    RLdata10000 <-  cbind((lapply(RLdata10000[, 1:4], cleanup)), RLdata10000[5:7])
  })

  # ... code omitted here

}
```